# How to restrict date entries dynamicly based on previously added line item to orders?

Tags: 7, datetime, commerce

To be a bit more precise...
I am building a webshop, where customers will be able to place orders containing celebration cakes. The main issue is, that the cake makers has got a limited capacity per day (as it takes time to make the cakes). Scaling the bakery and the staff suddenly is not an option. The client want to also avoid calling the customer, if their chosen date is already been fully booked when they placed the order (and is also not professional). For that reason I would like to monitor the incoming orders, and if the ordered cakes reaches the daily limit, then not to allow further orders to be placed for that day.
I can make A custom module, which is collecting the dates into a table and also adding quantities to that as well, But I am struggling to restrict the available dates based on that list.
So the question is simple. Is there a way to overcome this issue? If yes (I feel it) then can someone give some instructions on how to solve this issue?